# Should we use [sound] or [audio]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just asked a question with the [audio](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) tag, on top of an existing question using [sound](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound). Which should we use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [sound](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) tag has been remapped to [audio](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) ← (main tag)

Answer (score 11):

- Stack Overflow: [sound] → [audio]
- Super User: [sound] → [audio]
- Unix & Linux: [sound] → [audio]
- Ask Ubuntu: [audio] → [sound]
- Apple: [sound] → [audio]
- Software Recommendations: <strike>both [sound] and [audio] exist, with a 1:3 usage ratio</strike> [sound] → [audio]

Conclusion: let's have both, merge them, and make [audio] the main tag.

Comment: Aww beat me to to the punch, and with a much more quality answer!

Answer (score 1):

Good question, **audio** would be my vote as **sound** implies more *content* related material then *production* or *consumption* related discussions.

I was not able to find a reference for this then. :(

Comment: I've often regretted that [unix.se] has a single tag for both emitting or recording sound (e.g. “my sound drivers aren't working”) and manipulating data that represents sound (e.g. transcoding and tagging audio files), but I don't think the words “sound” vs “audio” express this distinction. In any case, on this site, only the emission/recording meaning is relevant.

Comment: Good point, the distinction may be regional (as per my reference fail), and the precedent that SE uses on other sites would be a better resource to pull form. :)