# Should we use: [GPU], [Graphics-Card], or [Video-Card]?

Tags: discussion, tags

As most gaming (or graphics editing work) towers contain some sort of graphics processing unit and they can be fairly pricey I suspect there will be several questions about them.

Current Options:

- **[GPU]** (Graphics Procsessing Unit)
- **[Graphics-Card]** or **[GraphicsCard]**
- **[Video-Card]** or **[VideoCard]**

What tag should we use to describe them and would it be worth having an auto merged tag as in [this question](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/should-we-use-sound-or-audio)? Have I missed any if so please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think **[gpu]** should be its own tag, as people can have questions about the GPU itself without asking about the card that it is on. The other 2 should be merged into one of the two with a hyphen. I prefer **[graphics-card]** over **[video-card]**, but that could just be me.

SuperUser has both **[graphic-card]** and **[video-card]** tags merged into **[graphics-card]**, and **[gpu]** is a stand-alone tag.

Comment: wow we posted at the exact same time, you have a good point. I think that makes sense to me. +1 :)

Comment: @Gram If something isn't quite right, let me know. I will edit it and try to make it more clear.

Comment: Everything is good, I just want to make sure we have some more comments before accepting so far this makes the most sense to me. :)

Comment: I think this is the logical choice, can we have someone with the rep needed do this?

Answer (score 0):

After some thought I am leaning towards **[GPU]** for the following reasons:

- **[Video-Card]** sounds like (although not true) it is only used for video editing and would not be used for games or 3D modeling.
- **[Graphics-Card]** is more inclusive than Video card, however it still refers to a physical card (for example PCIe) that excludes [integrated solutions](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hd-graphics/hd-graphics-developer.html).
- **[GPU]** includes video editing cards, gaming cards and integrated solutions. On the flip side it also enables discussions about phone and tablet cards such as the [Andreno](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/adreno-gpu-sdk/gpu).

This *needs* to be a community decided item so I will leave this open to see if this is the best direction or if we should go another direction.

Comment: This makes sense to me, although we might end up needing a distinction between desktop-class and mobile-class (and integrated!) GPUs.

Comment: Yes good point.